# vbscript / Classic ASP - Is there any way to get your own file name programmatically?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, filenames

I was just reviewing some old code and found the following (inside foo.asp):

```
Const ASP_FILENAME = "foo.asp"  ' TODO: Update this to the name of this file (if changed)
```

The variable is only used for logging errors.  (ie. "Error in foo.asp - Could not create xxxxx object.") Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the now-defunct Aspfaq.com (thanks to [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20070203053627/http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/files/directories-fso/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-url/page.html)):

**How do I get the name of the current URL / page?**

This one is pretty easy, but there are two parts.

To retrieve the name of the current file, you can use any of these:

```
<% 
    Response.Write Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") & "<br>" 
    Response.Write Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO") & "<br>" 
    Response.Write Request.ServerVariables("URL") & "<br>" 
%>
```

To make that path local (for example, to use with FileSystemObject), just apply the server.mappath() method to the result.

To get the entire URL, including the http:// or https:// prefix, you can do this:

```
<% 
    prot = "http" 
    https = lcase(request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")) 
    if https <> "off" then prot = "https" 
    domainname = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") 
    filename = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") 
    querystring = Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING") 
    response.write prot & "://" & domainname & filename & "?" & querystring 
%>
```

To get the page name ONLY, use something like this:

```
<% 
    scr = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") & "<br>" 
    if instr(scr,"/")>0 then 
        scr = right(scr, len(scr) - instrRev(scr,"/")) 
    end if 
    response.write scr 
%>
```

Or, without the IF logic:

```
<% 
    scr = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") & "<br>" 
    loc = instrRev(scr,"/") 
    scr = mid(scr, loc+1, len(scr) - loc) 
    response.write scr 
%>
```

Now. If your file is an #INCLUDE within another file, the above scripts will produce the name of the CALLING file (since the included file is first integrated into the calling script, then the ASP within it is all executed in the context of the 'parent' file). One way you can work around this is to re-populate a current_filename variable before loading each include file, for example:

```
<% 
      current_filename = "filetoinclude.asp" 
 %> 

<!--#include file='filetoinclude.asp'-->
```

(And no, don't try passing current_filename as a variable to the #INCLUDE directive; see Article #2042.)

Then, in filetoinclude.asp:

```
<% 
    Response.Write "Current file: " & current_filename 
%>
```

Of course, you could just as easily hard-code the filename inside of each include file. But I suppose that solution would somewhat defeat the purpose of retrieving that information at least somewhat dynamically.

Comment: Current Url <> Current file name.  It could be an include file, for example.

Comment: If that is an issue for the OP, this site suggests a means of handling that scenario too.

Comment: Please see my answer below for a `__FILE__` magic constant equivalent in Classic ASP :)

Answer (score 4):

You could parse `Request.ServerVariables("url")` to get the filename portion. A google search found [this code](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/ASP/Q_22678316.html), to which i don't claim credit, which uses the SCRIPT_NAME server variable which seems to make more sense indeed, also taking any url rewriting in to account that might be in place:

```
function getFileName(fpath, returnExtension)
        tmp = fpath
        if instrRev(tmp,"/") > 0 then
              tmp = mid(tmp, instrRev(tmp,"/")+1)
        end if
        if returnExtension = false then
              if instrRev(tmp,".") > 0 then
                    tmp = left(tmp, instrRev(tmp,".")-1)
              end if
        end if
        getFileName = tmp
  end function

  filename = request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
  Const ASP_FILENAME = getFileName(filename, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if server.mappath exists on traditional asp, but if so you could use if to know the page filename.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying that anyone here [insert discrete throat clearing cough here] still uses Classic ASP for maintaining and supporting legacy applications, but I recently had the need to do something similar. Refusing to settle for the "it's impossible with Classic ASP" responses out there, I set out to find a way and came up with the following solution.

This approach basically leverages underlying OS commands to literally determine the **current filename** (whose result is equivalent to using the `__FILE__` magic constant in PHP) regardless of whether it's a file include (`*.inc`) or the script itself (`*.asp`).

First, to support some sanitization (you can do this some other more "optimal" way if you wish):

```
'Regex helpers
Function NewRegex(ByVal pattern, ByVal ignore_case, ByVal global)
  Set NewRegex = New RegExp
  NewRegex.Pattern = pattern
  NewRegex.IgnoreCase = ignore_case
  NewRegex.Global = global
End Function

Function RegexMatch(ByVal pattern, ByVal subject)
  RegexMatch = RegexMatches(subject, pattern, True, False)
End Function

Function RegexMatches(ByVal subject, ByVal pattern, ByVal ignore_case, ByVal global)
  RegexMatches = NewRegex(pattern, ignore_case, global).Test(subject)
End Function
```

And now for a time of "reflection:"

```
Function GetCurrentFilename(ByVal uniqueId)
  '1. Enforce uniqueId format
  If Not RegexMatch("^[0-9a-f]+$", uniqueId) Then
    Exit Function
  End If

  '2. Use findstr to scan "readable" files in current directory for uniqueId
  Dim shell, cmd, process, fs, filename
  Set shell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  'See findstr /? for details on switches used below
  'cmd = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c findstr /P /M /C:"uniqueId" "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\includes\*"
  cmd = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMSPEC%") & " /c findstr /P /M /C:""" & uniqueId & """ """ & Server.MapPath(".") & "\*"""
  Set process = shell.Exec(cmd)

  '3. Use Scripting.FileSystemObject to return the filename portion of the first result returned
  Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  GetCurrentFilename = fs.GetFileName(process.StdOut.ReadLine())

  Set fs = Nothing
  Set process = Nothing
  Set shell = Nothing
End Function
```

Then, inside whatever file you want to "inspect" the current filename, simply drop the following line, passing in some unique identifier that should not exist in any other file in the current directory but this one:

```
'myfile.inc
Response.Write "This is in " & GetCurrentFilename("908ab098c")
```

The result:

```
This is in somefile.inc
```

Oh, and if you're interested in what I needed to use this for, here's what it looks like used in a simple breakpoint function:

```
Function Breakpoint(ByVal line_no, ByVal uniqueId, ByVal msg)
  Dim fn
  fn = GetCurrentFilename(uniqueId)

  Response.Write "[!] Breakpoint hit at Line " & CLng(line_no) & " in " & fn & ": " & Server.HtmlEncode(msg) & vbNewLine
  Response.End
End Function
```

Such that on Line 20 of my code, if I wanted to add my own breakpoint, it would look like this:

```
Breakpoint 20, "B0001", "Some debug output here"
```

Output:

```
[!] Breakpoint hit at Line 20 in somefile.inc: Some debug output here
```

Happy coding!

Comment: This looks like a lot of work for no purpose.  If I have to manually place a unique identifier in each and every file, why not just make the identifier "myfilename.asp"?  The whole point of __FILE__ is that you can drop it in anywhere and it figures itself out.  (For example, inside a function that may run within any number of files)